# How do I access a plain Ether transaction event in a Solidity Ethereum smart contract dApp?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, decentralized-applications

When a user sends some Ether to a smart contract/dApp address, is there a way I can access that transaction in my smart contract? Like a built-in method that's invoked, that I can add some code to?

My ideal work flow, if it's possible:

1. User sends Ether to my dApp address.
2. A function is invoked in my smart contract code.
3. Within that function, I can create some logic, like add their address to some state, etc.

Ideally, I want to avoid a user having to invoke a particular public function of the contract, but instead just send Ether to the dApp address.

If the user has to invoke a particular function, I have to start thinking about services like [MEW](https://www.myetherwallet.com/), or I have to build a web2 frontend app that integrates with the [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) browser extension or something. This seems like a lot of work, but is this the way it has to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [receive()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#receive-ether-function) special function that gets executed when you send ETH to the contract address and not specify any function to execute (i.e. the `data` field of the transaction is empty).

You can get the sender address through the `msg.sender` global variable and the amount through `msg.value`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    mapping (address => uint256) contributions;

    receive() external payable {
        contributions[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The docs state that the receive function can only rely on 2300 gas being available, so I might have to bear that in mind and keep the code to a minimum. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: @PeterJLangley The 2300 limit is used only in some cases, for example when another contract invokes your `receive()` function from their snippet `payable(yourContract).transfer(amount);`... If you just send the amount from an end address, the limit is not applied.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. This is exactly what I was looking for.